# Resizing UITextView and the section containing it without overdrawing next tableview section

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

I have a static table with four sections in it. The third section contains a UITextView that I'd like to resize if the user inputs more than one line. I managed to get this working but my resized textView overdraws the last table section.

I found a lot of older articles on this with different solutions but none really worked for me for my case of static tables.

What I've done was made my controller implement UITextViewDelegate and wrote this method:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    var frame = textView.frame
    frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height
    textView.frame = frame

    tableView?.beginUpdates()
    tableView?.endUpdates()
}
```

Some articles suggest writing a height constraint and then putting this inside the above method:

```
let size = reminderNameTextInput.bounds.size
let newSize = reminderNameTextInput.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat.max))

// Resize the cell only when cell's size is changed
if size.height != newSize.height {
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    tableView?.beginUpdates()
    tableView?.endUpdates()
}
```

Regardless, the outcome is the same: the textView grows and overdraws the next tableviewsection.

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE 1:**
Let me show you what I mean by the text "overgrowing" the parts below it:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2**
This is what happens if I recalculate the cell height in heightForRowAtIndexPath. It completely overdraws the sections below it instead of shifting them down:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me in the same use case as yours, put it in textViewDidChange:

```
let size = textView.bounds.size

let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat.max))
var estimatedHeight = newSize.height > MINIMUM_HEIGHT ? newSize.height : MINIMUM_HEIGHT

textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, textView.frame.width, estimatedHeight)
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
tableView?.beginUpdates()
tableView?.endUpdates()
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

Comment: Thanks. Where do you put this code? In the textViewDidChange function? What is 'self' in 'self.frame'?

Comment: yes, in textViewDidChange. The frame is of the text view. For my purposes I subclassed it, edited for clarification.

Comment: This does the same thing as my code - it grows the textView over the next Table View Section in a not very nice way. (Instead of moving the remaining section down with the growing UITextView.)

Comment: The problem is somewhere else then. Without seeing more code/storyboard setup it's all shooting in the dark.

Comment: What happens when you preset the text to lorem ipsum or something equally long (few lines worth of text), does it behave correctly? In heightForRowAtIndexPath, try adding `if indexPath.row == TEXT_VIEW_CELL_INDEX_PATH {
            return self.textViewCell.estimatedHeight
        }`

Comment: I updated the screenshot with a really long text with new lines (carriage returns.) I can't insert your code, it doesn't understand 'textViewCell'. (I don't use custom UITableViewCell subclasses.) I use a static table. (I'm recreating the iOS Reminders App's detail view.)

Comment: Drag your static cell to your controller then and make an outlet?

Comment: What I've done is make the estimatedHeight in your code global. Then I inserted the code you suggested in heightForRowAtIndexPath. The text view now grows. However, the problem is that it still grows on top of the elements below it. I inserted another screenshot to show this.

Comment: How do you allow word wrapping for UITextView in your solution? (I.e., if the text is longer than the row width then the text continues in the next row.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using autolayouts? 
When using autolayouts and size-classes  , you can fix the problem from storyboard

**UITextView Constraint Setting :**

1. Set left, right, top, bottom margin constraint
2. Change the priority of Content Compression Resistance Prority  from 750 to 900 or higher than 750 and Content Hugging Priority 250 t0 260.
3. Turn off scrolling enabled.
   [image]

   Also you must add the following  line in   `textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView)` method,

   `tableView?.beginUpdates()`


   `tableView?.endUpdates()`

Then should work !

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The textView now doesn't grow at all. I set up the constraints on the UITextView, which resulted in 2 vertical and 2 horizontal space constraints (on content view and text view, each). Then I set the UITextView's Content Hugging and Compression resistance priority as you specified with the begin and end updates.

Comment: 'Scrolling Enabled' must be deselected from the storyboard also .Without doing that it may not work .

Comment: The UITextView still doesn't grow. Now the text just goes beyond the visible area of the screen. Using the back-arrow I have to move back so I can see the cursor again. But the textView doesn't grow.